# Count occurrences by object id in std::multimap

Tags: c++, std, multimap

I'm trying to find the occurrences of an object in a std::multimap

Here is my object Point:

```
class Point
{
public:

    Point(string id, float x, float y, float z);

    string m_id;
    float m_x;
    float m_y;
    float m_z;

    //I want to count with this operator
    bool operator==(const Point &point) const
    {
        return point.m_id == m_id;
    }

    bool operator <( const Point &point ) const
    {
        return ( m_y < point.m_y );
    }

};
```

**Here is my function (solution):**

```
int countOccurences(multimap<Point, string> multimap, Point point)
{
    int result = 0;

    for (auto it = multimap.begin(); it != multimap.end(); it++)
        if (it->first == point)
            result++;

    return result;
}
```

My main:

```
multimap<Point, string> places;

Point point1("point", 0, 0, 0 );
Point point2("cake", 0, 0, 0 );
Point point3("point", 0, 0, 0 );

places.insert(make_pair(point1, ""));
places.insert(make_pair(point2, ""));
places.insert(make_pair(point3, ""));

cout << "CORRECT = 2" << endl;
cout << "COUNT = " << places.count(point3) << endl;
cout << "MY_COUNT = " << countOccurences(places, point3) << endl;
```

Initially, I wanted to count the number of occurrences with the operator==, but it was counting with the operator<. Using the function countOccurrences() is my solution.

Comment: [You need to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: For one thing, we have no idea what an `S` is.

Comment: keys in a map have to be unique.  The key either exists or there is only one.  If you want to see if a key exist then use [`std::map::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find)

Comment: Maybe std::multimap should be used instead. However why is the code not using map::find()?

Comment: Use `map::count` ! http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/count

Comment: Show how you have defined `operator<<` for `O`.

Comment: Without seeing the code where objects are added to the map it's rather difficult to say precisely why this isn't working. @Xirema's comment about posting a minimal, complete, and verifiable example is pertinent here. Please edit your question and include such an example. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis even though this isn't a complete sample, it has enough information to say why it isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But it doesn't works, il only returns 1 and **there are at least 2
>   objects in my map that have same id**

It's a `std::map`. You cannot have two objects with the same key, and I assume you're trying to use the `m_id` filed of `O` as your key. Try using [`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) instead.

And, to count the number of items, use `map::count()` (which for std::map can only return one or zero!)

Comment: ... And consider using `map::find(T)`

Comment: "You cannot have two objects with the same ID." actually this not quite true. You assumed that `id` is used as a key for `std::map` but nothing shows that in the code.

Comment: @Slava, based on the code shown that was probably the easiest assumption to make :)

Comment: @Roddy maybe so, but you should mention that in the answer

Comment: @Slava. Actually it's pretty clear in the code. The map key type is of `O` and the equality operator for `O` compares the `m_id` field. So the map can't contain two objects with equal `m_id`. Referring to that as 'id' isn't a huge leap.

Comment: @Roddy equality operator is not used by map, so in theory object could be sorted by different field or their combination and then 2 objects with the same m_id can be in the map and it would make sense to use `std::count()` instead of `std::map::count()`. Most probably this is not the case, but possible. So if you make an assumption you should mention it, otherwise your answer could be completely incorrect.

Comment: @slava "equality operator not used by map". Wow, I hadn't realised that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use a `std::map`, you only have one value for each key. If you've inserted different values for one key, then you have *overwritten* previous ones with newer ones.

As pointed out in the comments, avoid the `std` algorithms that `std::map` has its own optimized versions of. Ones like `std::count_if` and `std::find_if` are *not* in `std::map` though.

Comment: Don't use the algorithms on a `map` or `multimap`, they're less efficient than using member functions - O(n) vs. O(log n).

Comment: "If you've inserted different values for one key, then you have overwritten previous ones with newer ones." if they are inserted by `std::map::insert` they are not overwritten

Comment: @mark - thanks for the correction, I changed that piece to better reflect this.

Comment: @slava - your clarification is correct and nothing I wrote says anything else.